# How to get specific xml tags with php

Tags: php, html, xml

I have this xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<book>
 <id id="EXE">
  Some text here
 </id>
 <ide charset="UTF-8"/>
  <h>Exercise</h>
 <toc level="1">Exercise books</toc>
 <p sfm="mt">This is the first exercise book.</p>
 <c id="1"/>
 <p>
  Some first text here
 </p>
 <p>
  Some second text here
 </p>
 <p>
  Some third text here
 </p>
 <c id="2" />
 <p>
  Another first text here
 </p>
 <p>
  Another second text here
 </p>
 <p>
  Another third text here
 </p>
</book> ...
```

Now this is my problem. I want to get the `<p>` tags after the first `<c>` tag with id = 1 with php. I was able to achieve getting every `<p>` tag in the main `<body></body>` tag this code

```
<?php
 $xml  = simplexml_load_file('bible/books/list%20of%20books_usfx.xml');
    foreach ($xml->book[0]->p as $chapter) {
   echo $chapter->asXML();
}
?>
```

and I succeeded, but how can i get every `<p>` tag after the first `<c id="1"/>` and before the `<c id="2" />` tag.

Comment: Uh, thanks but i don't think this is a duplicate of that. It did not solve my problem.

Comment: The concept is EXACTLY what you need. Just because the nitty gritty details don't match is not the answer's problem. If you learn the concept, you'll be able to do this for all of your related problems. Just like teaching a man to fish v.s. giving a man a fish.

Comment: Yea, but when i did not find the solution, I tried searching xpath on php.net and it is what i am currently doing. As for those answers, they did not solve my problems. But thanks by the way.

Comment: Use the absolute path, ex: `$xml  = simplexml_load_file('/home/user/bible/books/list%20of%20books_usfx.xml');` Try removing the `%20`.

Comment: @Tuga: The problem is not with the path of the file. @Marc B: i tried `xpath("//book/p")` and it returned every p which is fine, but when i tried `xpath("//book/c[1]/*")` it returned nothing. Is it because that `<c id="1"/>` tag has no children?

Comment: I have found the solution. I tried the following code: `$chapter = $xml1->xpath("//book[1]/c[1]/following::p[1]");
        while(list( , $node) = each($chapter)) {
     echo $node->asXML();
    }`